# Nginx and FastCGI downloads PHP files instead of processing them

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I'm running on Windows 7 (64-bit), with PHP 5.4.12, and Nginx 1.5.8.

I have read many tutorials on setting this up, and troubleshooting this issue, which is that when requesting a PHP file from my localhost, it downloads it as a file instead of displaying the PHP page. Below is my nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen 8081;
        server_name localhost;
        access_log C:/nginx/logs/access.log;
        error_log C:/nginx/logs/error.log;
        root C:/nginx/html;

        fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

        location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
          fastcgi_index  index.php;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

}
```

I'm running nginx.exe manually through the command prompt.
I've also tried starting php-cgi.exe manually first at a separate command prompt, like so:

```
C:\php5.4.12\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000
```

The php file I'm requesting is within C:/nginx/html, and I'm requesting it as:

```
http://localhost:8081/info.php
```

And it downloads it. The contents of this PHP file are:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

How can I possibly get my PHP scripts to run in this environment. Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change `default_type  application/octet-stream;` to `default_type text/html;`
Maybe your php-script does not set a content MIME type and it goes from nginx.

Comment: Interesting, but it worked for me too! Would be great to hear the tech explanation for this...

Answer (score 0):

Try placing " * " here

```
location ~* \.php$ {
```

There is something wrong with your paths, and nginx does not know the path accessed via URL is the path it should pass through "fastcgi_pass". Therefore, it gives the file for download.

Check your error log from :

```
C:/nginx/logs/error.log;
```

Do you have a "C:/nginx/html/info.php;"?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you have the `http2` directive for port 80 on the server.
`http2` works only under `https`. Therefore, if you remove `http2`, it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was http2 enabled on port 80 for me too. Disabling it solved the issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31319622)